# Trying to edit a .class file - android dtudio

Tags: android-studio, nullpointerexception, .class-file

I been trying to edit an existing .class file in a project created by eflipse.
In Android-Studio the upper bar says "Decompiled .class file, bytecode version: 50.0(Java6)".
When i'm trying to edit something (write/delete something) inside the .class file I see a N ullPointerException in the event log.
anyone knows how to deal with it?

Comment: Ofcourse nothig is changing inside the file

Comment: Have you tried using a different tool?

Comment: .class files are compiled code. Why are you trying to edit the compiled code and not the source code that it was compiled from?

Comment: I'm trying to change the site address that the progrem is reffering to a localhost for test purpose. Why is it not possible in the 'Android Studio'? Why do I have to close the Android Studio - open my eclipse - change what I want - close eclipse - open Android Studio?